# Sequlize promises causing very high connection usage in MariaDB

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

In my web app we allow user to upload a tab delimited file with records which gets processed by a backend API written in ExpressJs (NodeJS). I use Sequlize to perform CRUD operations. I am noticing a very high connection usage by Sequlize esp when I get a file with 200+ records. This results in SequelizeConnectionAcquireTimeoutError where DB operations fails as it can't acquire DB connection.

In my API layer I simply loop through the supplied records (hundreds) and fire off INSERT and UPDATE operations for each record. As Sequlize CRUD operations are Javascript promises and Node being a single threaded architecture, I believe these requests gets queued up and first few hundred requests gets hold of the DB connections while the remaining requests times out (acquire time settings in the connection pool). Is there any way you can address this other than using a queue mechanism or some sort of throttling within the loop?

Answer (score 0):

To be able to fix this issue, ensure connection pool has been fixed on your nodejs sequelize code. Here is the sample code:-

```
const sequelize = new Sequelize(/* ... */, {
  // ...
  pool: {
    max: 5,
    min: 0,
    acquire: 30000,
    idle: 10000
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks @ekibet I have already tuned these params though while they work, I am not convinced with how Sequlize manages CRUD operations a promises. My new pool setting are as per below.  I have to set VERY HIGH value i.e. 300 for max connections and likewise had to config the MariaDB to match that high value
"dialect": "mysql",
"dialectOptions": {
       "connectTimeout": 220000
    },
    "pool": {
      "max": 300,
      "acquire": 220000,
      "idle": 10000
    },